# reading raw binary data from blob columns using oracle backend

Tags: django, oracle, orm, blob, blobstorage

I'm working with oracle legacy DB and need to read and write binary data (png images, and and MDL Molfiles).
Django's inspectdb command generated text fields for these columns, saying that's only a guess.
Now, when I'm trying to retrieve a value from this class fields i get:
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte.
error.

Is there any way to read and write these columns?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BlobField(models.TextField):
    description = "Stores raw binary data"

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds = _adjust_keywords(kwds)
        super(BlobField, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "BlobField"

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection=None, prepared=False):
        return value

    def to_python(self, value):
        return Blob(value)
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What is a Blob class, _adjust_keyword method?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Not only this function is missing but I wrote complete implementation working with all db backends. I will put it on github soon.